# MS SQL-Server 2014 and SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: server-setup, sql-server-2014

How do I install `SQL Server Data Tools` for `MS SQL-Server 2014`?

In previous versions of MS-SQL-Server those tools come with the regular installation-package for the server itself. For SQL-Server 2014 the options are gone.

Here you can see the option, I'm looking for, for older Versions of MS-SQL-Server:
[The option for SQL-Server 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC2PE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Latest SQL Server Data Tools
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: apparently the tool is not packed with the sql-server itself anymore. And apparently the specific function I was looking is now    SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence.